# How to use MuteButton video component?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to create a button, which plays/stops background music in my flash game. I could use Button component with custom images, but I found MuteButton component which appears to have everything that I need, including images. The problem is that I don't know how to set up MuteButton and is that even possible to use without using FLVPlayback component on first place?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable mute button in single button you can use

```
var volumeOn:Boolean = true;
var globalVolume:Sound = new Sound();
btnSoundOff.onRelease = function():Void {
 if (volumeOn) {
  globalVolume.setVolume(0);
 } else {
  globalVolume.setVolume(100);
 }
 volumeOn = !volumeOn;
}
```